# Group images by reference code

Tags: php, mysql

**I have a table of images, I need to list all the images of a product to be able to display them in a row:**

[image]

**I have this query:**

```
<?php
require_once 'assets/files/meekrodb.php';

$results = DB::query("SELECT * FROM images");
foreach ($results as $row) {
  echo $row['imagen'] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

**Which shows me this:**

[image]

**I want to group by the field "product" and display in a row like this:**
[image]

**Can you help me, thanks in advance!**

Comment: Have you tried DB::query("SELECT imagen FROM images group by product"); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by product as you fetch the results like this:

```
$results = DB::query("SELECT * FROM images");

foreach ($results as $row) {
    // use product as key, add image to array at that key
    $products[$row['product']][] = $row['imagen'];
}
```

Then output the groups like this:

```
foreach ($products as $product => $images) {
    echo implode(', ', $images) . '<br>';
}
```